# how to hide base class properties in child form in C#

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, datagridview

i have two different class (**Invoice class and invoiceSummary class**). and i have inherit like this **Invoice:InvoiceSummary**.

i have used this code to hide properties from child class

```
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string ItemNo
    {            
        get { return itemNo;  }
        set { itemNo = value; }
    }
```

but above code - Hide my properties in both class, that's mean (base class and child class)

**My Question is :** i need to hide this properties only from Child class that's mean ***(InvoiceSummary class) datagridview*** at the same time i need to shows this same **properties in my Base class datagridview**.. please give me a solution..

invoice class code

```
  namespace BillingSystem.Business
   {
    [Serializable()]
    public class Invoice : ISerializable
    {
    private string invoiceid;
    private string itemNo;

    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Invoiceid
    {
        get { return invoiceid; }
        set { invoiceid = value; }
    }

   [Browsable(false)]
    public string ItemNo
    {

        get { return itemNo;  }
        set { itemNo = value; }
    }
```

InvoiceSummary Class properties

```
     public class invoiceSummary :Invoice
     {
      private int no;
      private string customerName;
      private int invoiceID;   
     }
```

for more details i have attached screenshot
 [InvoiceSummary dataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAWjg.png)

Comment: Check the "sealed" modifier in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the `sealed` modifier to the property in the base class.

```
public sealed string ItemNo
{            
    get { return itemNo;  }
    set { itemNo = value; }
}
```

This will prevent classes that inherit from the base class from overriding this property.

Comment: why this errors showing like this "cannot be sealed because it is not an override" ?

Comment: please give me a solution